# better and fastest way to get result from a DQL query using Select

Tags: dql, documentum

Can anybody tell me how to make this DQL query more faster and better because i am using a SELECT to get a very large amount of rows from a very large Table created in Documentum

select r_object_id from table1(all)
where table1_attribute1 = '12345'
and table1_attribute2 > 0
and table1_attribute3 not in (
select table2_attribute1 from table2
) enable (return_range 1 1000 'r_object_id')

Answer (score 0):

You might have to look into creating indexes on database. This can be done directly (SQL) or through DQL. I prefer the latter since column names are the same and you can rebuild them though DQL.

Answer (score 0):

by "table" you mean "object type" right? you can try creating a SQL which may perform faster avoiding some joins